# How to switch context from Native App to Web App in Appium

Tags: firefox, appium

We are Unable to switch context from Native app to Web app.
Kindly suggest us a way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Set contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    if (contextName.contains(“WEBVIEW”)){
      driver.context(contextName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here we are getting only a single context name - NativeApp. So unable to find Webview context when trying the above code.

Comment: Unable to switch to Webview on real device , but where as on local emulator it is working fine. Trying the code on AWS android device